# What is the function in the Physics StackExchange website picture?

Tags: discussion, design

I'm sorry if this isn't a question fit for this site, but what exactly is the function that's plotted in the website logo/picture? It looks kind of like a simple decaying exponential multiplied by a sinusoid, but I feel like it may be something really interesting that the creator put for a good story/laugh.

[image]

Comment: For the record, it's pretty niche. Most physicists wouldn't recognize the shape and don't work on the symmetry breaking it comes from, and most people in the world who know about *a* Mexican hat function are in [signal processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_wavelet), not physics.